# Updating a single image of an IKImageBrowserView

Tags: cocoa, macos, appkit

I searched everywhere and can't seem to find a way to do this.

I am currently making a simple application to help our user configure image metadata for another application.

I present the list of image to be configured in an IKImageBrowserView.  The user selects an image. which is then displayed in another view and adds stuff to it.

I'd like to be able to update the IKImageBrowserView thumbnail "live", as the user manipulates the image.  I am able to take a "screenshot" of the view on which he is working but can't for the life of me find a way to update this single IKImageBrowserView item without having to call reloadData.

Is there a way to update a single image in an IKImageBrowserView without calling reloadData?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [-imageVersion](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserItem_Protocol/IKImageBrowserItem_Reference.html) method. This will cause the cache for that item to be invalidated. There also appears to be a private `-reloadCellDataAtIndex:` method that might be of interest. Updating the image's version and calling `-reloadData` should be sufficient though.

Comment: I had to jump to some other work right now but you are right, invalidating the cache for one image and reloading data should do the trick.